# BackgroundLocationListener not calling Rest API when app is in background

Tags: codenameone

I am using codenameone `BackgroundLocationListener` to send device location to server. (I am calling standard GET request in the listener.)

This works fine when app is in foreground, but when I switch to different (gps navigation) app, navigate to home screen, or lock the phone, web service is not called anymore.

I am registering listener with standard code when button is pressed:

```java
lmbBtn.addActionListener((evt) -> {
   LocationManager.getLocationManager().setBackgroundLocationListener(LocationListenerImpl.class);
});
```

And this is the listener implementation:

```java
/**
 * (c) Starbug
 * https://www.starbug.eu/
 */
package eu.starbug.uberis.test;

import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.io.rest.Rest;
import com.codename1.location.Location;
import com.codename1.location.LocationListener;
import com.codename1.location.LocationManager;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author Peter Husarik
 */
public class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener {

    private String info = "B";

    public LocationListenerImpl() {
    }

    public LocationListenerImpl(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @Override
    public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
        String url = "https://webservice/gpsLogger/?";
        url += "time=" + new Date().getTime();
        url += "&lat=" + location.getLatitude();
        url += "&lon=" + location.getLongitude();
        if(info != null && !info.isEmpty()){
            url += "&info=" + info;
        }

        Rest.get(url).fetchAsString((v) -> {
            //
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void providerStateChanged(int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case LocationManager.AVAILABLE:
            case LocationManager.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            case LocationManager.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.p("LocationListener providerStateChanged: " + newState);
//                ToastBar.showInfoMessage("LocationListener providerStateChanged: " + newState);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't background listener listen for location updates when app is not running?

Comment: It might be a problem and these things are pretty hard to debug... Generally you're not supposed to do that, you have background fetch which is a separate API supposedly for background download. On which OS is this happening and can you get access to the native logs, they usually provide the detail of what happened

Comment: This is tested on Android 9.
I can provide logs if necessary. But what scenario to log and should I check for my application or all device logs?
If I am not supposed to do that this way, how can I log device location to the server?

Comment: Just look at the output from the device and filter based on your app. That's pretty much the only way to debug this. Background location tracking works partially and has issues as OS's try to strengthen privacy protections exactly against these use cases.